# Paypal custom checkout for Express Checkout

Tags: php, paypal

I want to customize it through the API and not the console.
As I understand from this documentation https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/merchant/SetExpressCheckout_API_Operation_NVP/

there are about four to five parameters &LOGOIMG, &HDRIMG, &CARTBORDERCOLOR,&PAYFLOWCOLOR.
So I am not able to use both logo image and header image together. Only one of them gets displayed if I give a url for both.
PAYFLOWCOLOR does not work at all.

Also for recurring express checkout both logo image and cart border color does not work.
Only header image works.

Has anyone else come across this error.

Comment: Are you working in the sandbox or live right now?  The live servers are actually using new checkout pages on the PayPal side that have completely broken the ability to utilize Unified Checkout (which is what you're referring to) as well as a few other features EC used to do well.  Supposedly their development team knows about it and are working on it, but it could be a week or 6 months before it's fixed.

Comment: right now I was using sandbox. Have you faced any such issues too?
Is there a place where its documented that this part is broken?

Comment: Well, the sandbox is actually working just fine for me, so if you're in the sandbox I'm not sure why you'd be having an issue.  The live servers are what recently changed, and they actually don't match the sandbox right now.  The new pages they launched on the liv server no longer support HDRIMG or the other things.  You have to set that up in your PayPal profile now.

Comment: Hey Andrew- thanks for your help, it started working with version=106, I was using 62.0

Comment: Although the surprising thing is PayPal documentation says it should work above version 52.0